# Get all comments by a set of users made the 24 hours prior to their last comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a many-to-one relationship between the models User and Comment.

I would like to collect, preferably in a hash, all comments made by a set of users the 24 hours prior to each user's last comment (including his/her last comment).

This is what I have come up with, but I dont know how to create the hash with comments only from the time span mentioned.

```
Comment.order('updated_at desc').where(user_id: array_of_users_ids).group_by(&:user).each do |user, comments|
  # rearrange the hash here?
end
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL solution for this would be a correlated subquery, made slightly tricky by non-standard date arithmetic depending on the RDBMS in use.

You'd be looking for a query such as:

```
select ...
from   comments
where  comments.user_id in (...) and
       comments.updated_at >= (
         select max(updated_at) - interval '1 day'
         from   comments c2
         where  c2.user_id = comments.user_id)
```

You ought to be able to achieve this with:

```
Comment.where(user_id: array_of_users_ids).
        where("comments.updated_at >= (
                 select max(updated_at) - interval '1 day'
                 from   comments c2
                 where  c2.user_id = comments.user_id)").
        order(... etc
```